# Oracle - Need query to max out CPU

Tags: oracle, resources, cpu-usage

Need few queries to generate load on CPU and eventually max it out to 100%.
The queries when executed should be able to generate high CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
declare 
    l_job_out integer;
    l_what dba_jobs.what%type;
    l_cpus_to_hog CONSTANT integer :=4;
    l_loop_count varchar2(10) := '500000000'; 
begin

/* 
** Create some jobs to load the CPU
*/
    for l_job in 1..l_cpus_to_hog loop 
        dbms_job.submit(
        job => l_job_out
        , what => 'declare a number := 1; begin for i in 1..'||l_loop_count||' loop a := ( a + i )/11; end loop; end;'
        );
        commit;   
        dbms_output.put_line( 'job - '|| l_job_out );
        select what into l_what 
        from dba_jobs 
        where job = l_job_out;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'what - '|| l_what );
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Good idea, but I'd recommend using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` instead of `DBMS_JOBS`.  The scheduler is much more powerful, easier to use, and easier to monitor, than the old jobs package.

Comment: thanks for the add i hope we could be useful for him

Comment: Wonderful! This did create some load on the PDB.
Applied instance caging on the CDB to help me further.